# Force some margin-top to one of 2 inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following code which is basically an image with some text on the right, all on the same line. I would like the text to be kind of vertically centered with the image :

```
|
|
img   myText here
|
|
```

Here is my code

```css
img, .info {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
<span class="info">
  <span>FOO</span>
  <span>BLAH</span>
</span>
```

I tried to apply some margin to the info class but it moves the img as well. How can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned use vertical-align to center the items vertically. Also, you have to make them inline-blocks to add a padding:

```css
img, .info {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.info {
    padding-left:32px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
<span class="info">
  <span>FOO</span>
  <span>BLAH</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`vertical-align:middle`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_vertical-align&preval=middle)

> The element is placed in the middle of the parent element

```css
img, .info {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
<span class="info">
  <span>FOO</span>
  <span>BLAH</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a wrapper, then vertical align them:
https://jsfiddle.net/g7mk4cp0/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
  <span class="info">
    <span>FOO</span>
    <span>BLAH</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper > img, .wrapper > span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try vertical align middle method

```css
 .holder img{
 vertical-align:middle;
 }
```

```html
<div class="holder">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
    <span class="info">
      <span>FOO</span>
      <span>BLAH</span>
    </span>

  </div>
```